# Remove string from href jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to remove # into href link, here's my link :

```
<a href="home/new/#hello">My link</a>
```

I target the href but I don't know how to remove the '#'

```
$(a).attr('href');
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Do you mean, removing everything after the ``#`` or only the sign itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your answer:-

```
$('a').attr('href').replace('#','');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$('a').attr('href',function(_,v){
   return v.replace('#','');
});
```